# onStartCommand of STICKY service is not called after restart

Tags: android, service, background-process

I have a sticky service for updating user status/location.

Android kills my service once in a while and restarts service, this is ok, but the problem is the `onStartCommand` is not called in these restarts.

Shall I set some specific flag?

Comment: so what method(s) is called when the service is restarted?

Comment: @pskink just onCreate

Comment: what platform version does it happen?

Comment: @pskink Oreo (8) on Pixel

Comment: I have the same problem, and it happens only with Oreo.  Have you found a solution?